# How do I approach this signals and systems question?

Tags: functions

The question seems very abstract to me as it doesn't really describe what it is asking for.

The problem states the following, let:

$$x[n]=\begin{cases}
n,&\text{if n is odd};\\\\
0,&\text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}$$

Determine $y[n] = x[2n]$

Basically that is the only thing given to me so I don't know exactly what I am supposed to do here. I do know that since it is formatted with the brackets, it will be something related to discrete time signals. Can anyone explain to me what they might be asking for here?

Thanks!

Comment: Well, $y[n]=0$.

Comment: How did you approach it though? Still confused on that part.

Comment: It says $x[n]=0$ otherwise, ie for even integers. So $x[2n]=0$. This is your $y[n]$.

Comment: Oh I see now, thank you so much for this clarification!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sequence is:

$ x[1] = 1 \\
x[2] = 0 \\
x[3] = 3 \\
x[4] = 0 \\
x[5] = 5 \\
...
$

therefore

$
y[n] = x[2n] \\
y[1] = x[2] = 0\\
y[2] = x[4] = 0\\
y[3] = x[6] = 0\\
...
$